# What factors determine whether a spacecraft/probe/satellite uses gyroscopes or propellant thrusters to rotate?

Tags: artificial-satellite, propulsion, spacecraft, attitude, reaction-wheel

Say I'm designing a probe or satellite. To control its attitude, I can add some gyros, or I can put thrusters on each corner, or I can add both and pick one in flight according to the situation. How do I decide which to use? How does it depend on the design lifetime, mass, expected frequency of attitude changes, and orbit of the probe?

It'd be great if you could support your explanation with an example or two.

Answer (score 17):

For the record, there's actually a third possibility, Magnetorquers. Here's why you would use one vs the other.

**Magnetorquers** - Inexpensive, low maintenance, but don't work in all situations. Used by LEO spacecraft typically, and small in size. They work by pushing off of a magnetic field.

**Reaction Wheels** (Or Gyros) - The trick here is that you can't take out a momentum change using only reaction wheels. You either need to stop the spacecraft from moving, or else offload the momentum with another form of propulsion. These work great if you can reasonable expect to have the spacecraft with the same angular momentum eventually. They tend to break down over time, but can last for many years. The reason they can't is because basically they exchange momentum from the spacecraft with momentum in the wheel. You can only make a permanent change if you are pushing against something external, or pushing something towards or away from you, Reaction Wheels just change the momentum until the wheel stops spinning. They can change the orientation, just not the momentum. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FidvWCDA_8w) for a good demonstration.

**Thrusters** - These work all the time, but use fuel. Thus, you are limited to how much you can use them based on the fuel load vs. the lifetime of the mission. Also their exhaust can be dangerous to your satellite, if it carries something sensitive - that is the case of the Hubble Space Telescope, where [thrusters could contaminate the optics](http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/basics/bsf11-2.php).

Bottom line is, you use what you can, and will cause the minimal impact to your spacecraft.

Comment: Why can a reaction wheel **not** make a permanent change in attitude?

Comment: Where the impulse will come from?

Comment: Impulse is defined as the change in **linear** momentum of a body, and is not relevant to a change in angular position...

Comment: Reaction Wheel's can't make permanent changes because they don't cause an external force on the spacecraft.

Comment: An external force is not needed to change the linear or angular position, only to change linear or angular velocity and momentum...

Comment: Don't forget Control Moment Gyroscopes, which use a different concept from reaction wheels.

Comment: @User58220: Good point, I've edited to clarify.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto The answer is stating that "[reaction wheels] cannot make permanent change in attitude" and also it states that "they can change orientation". Isn't "attitude" the same thing as "orientation"? Can I permanently re-orient a spacecraft from looking at Betelgeuse to looking at Vega with only the reaction wheels? Before and after this maneuver the angular momentum would be zero (WRT to distant stars). Net momentum change is also zero. Only the attitude=orientation would change permanently. Is that possible with reaction wheels only?

Comment: Orientation is a part of attitude, but yes, I can see I still need to improve this answer. You can change the pointing of the spacecraft, you just can't take out the spin of the spacecraft. As most satellites will spin slightly naturally...

Comment: For a slightly connected situation, Google on "motorcycle angular momentum" to see how motorcycle jumpers in a jump (effectively VeryLEO) use throttle/brakes to change their angular orientation in the air, using the bike wheels as reaction wheels.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the answer of @PearsonArtPhoto, it ***is*** possible to use a reaction wheel to make a permanent change in attitude.  Consider a non-rotating satellite carrying a non-rotating gyro.  If a motor is used to spin up the gyro, Newton's Third Law requires a reverse torque be exerted on the satellite, and it will start to rotate in the opposite direction.  After a suitable period of time, the gyro is braked to a stop, at which point conservation of angular momentum dictates that the satellite and gyro are both non-rotating again, with the satellite pointing in the desired, new, direction.

If the satellite experiences any ***outside*** torque, then the reaction wheel can be used to store the new angular momentum, keeping the attitude of the satellite fixed. In this case, the gyro must be kept rotating constantly, until the angular momentum can be "dumped", or some opposite outside torque comes along...

Comment: Could you clarify a bit please? When "the gyro is braked to a stop" the momentum from it is transferred back to the braking body, so you're essentially back at where you started before the gyro was spun (momentum conservation). Reaction wheels can store limited translational momentum since their spin rate is limited and they can't spin indefinitely, so I have to agree with Pearson that their change in attitude is not permanent either. Am I missing the point you're trying to make? How can you "dump" angular momentum stored in reaction wheels?

Comment: Try this:  stand up, turn around, and sit down again.  Do you snap back to your original position? You temporarily changes your angular velocity, transferring angular momentum to the earth.  When you stop turning, AM is re-arranged as it was, but the change in angular position is permanent...

Comment: Only that there's no Earth to sit on in space ... then what?

Comment: The earth was your reaction wheel;  in space, use what you can.  An astronaut floating in space could twiddle his thumbs  While twiddling, he would rotate (slowly!) forward (or back, depending on the direction of twiddle) in pitch;  when he stopped twiddling, he would stop rotating.  He wouldn't snap back to his pre-twiddle attitude...

Comment: That last analogy is not really helping, but let's pretend that twiddling thumbs can serve as a momentum storage device, then yes, he would stop. That's the same point I was making. You don't seem to fully appreciate what "attitude" means in flight dynamics. It's about the object's orientation in an [inertial frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_frame_of_reference). That "he would stop rotating" is his initial attitude. So yes, you would in fact revert back to where you started as far as attitude is concerned. Therefore, no permanent change in attitude.

Comment: So, attitude means "state of rotation"?  What term is used to describe the orientation; as in, "We need to keep the Hubble's _____?_____ constant while we image that galaxy"?

Comment: It's still attitude, but for that example you give, you'd probably be referring to one or more of its three axes fixed with respect to the observed object. So it's more "rotation rate with respect to [...]" where it can of course also be 0, or sometimes referred to as _fixed_, _frozen_ or _maintained attitude_. For more, Wikipedia's article on [Attitude control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attitude_control) actually isn't that bad, I can't find any glaring errors in it.

Comment: This is incorrect. When you brake the gyro to a stop, the gyro exerts a torque in the rotation direction on the satellite. So as your gyro stops, the satellite will start spinning.